# Actionscript 3.0 : Controlling child movieclips added with an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, slideshow

I'm trying to build a generic slide show flash file controlled with key presses... right and left arrow to go to next / previous slide, down and up to call / uncall the single animations / bullet points / whatever on a single slide.
So far I managed to get a file that can load all the pages from a movieclip and flick through them with right and left arrow and a nice fade out and fade in effect, even when flicking very fast.
What I do not get at all after several hours and lots of google searches is how to now control the single page movieclips. I uploaded the file so far:

http://www.broesel-brzelius.de/zeug/slide.zip

You can see that my (as of yet crude) attempt to control the pageHolder.Pages.page1 movieclip to gotoAndStop(2) just results in the pageHolder.Pages movieclip that was loaded to position 0 in the array to go to frame 2 and thus display the second page.

Code so far:

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
import com.greensock.*; 
import flash.display.MovieClip; 

// instantiate a variable to find number of pages 
var numberOfPages:Pages = new Pages(); 
// instantiate an array to hold the page movieclips 
var pageArray:Array = new Array(); 
// instantiate a container to hold the pages 
var pageHolder:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
// declare variables that will hold reference to the current page IDs
var targetIDold:int = 0;
var targetIDnew:int = 0;
// declare a variable that will hold the current direction of slide movement
var movement:int = -1;

// call a function that builds the application 
// pass in the number of pages in fl_prevSlide 
buildApp(numberOfPages.totalFrames);

// this function builds the application
function buildApp(n:int):void
{
    // declare variables for the pages
    var p:Pages;
    // instantiate a new Page, send its playhead to the current value of i+1
    // it is necessary to add 1 to the value of i, since i starts at 0, while the timeline starts at 1
    for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        p = new Pages(); 
        p.gotoAndStop(i + 1); 
        pageArray.push(p);
    } 
    // set the position of the pageHolder relative to the buttonHolder 
    pageHolder.x = pageHolder.y = 0; 
    // add the first page (at index 0) from pageArray to pageHolder 
    pageHolder.addChild(pageArray[targetIDnew]); 
    // add pageHolder and buttonHolder to the stage 
    addChild(pageHolder); 
} 

//Adding Listener and corresponding function to change between slides
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, f_changeSlide);
function f_changeSlide(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == 37) // left arrow
    {
        f_prevSlide();
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 32) // right arrow or space
    {
        f_nextSlide();
    }
}
function f_prevSlide():void
{
    if(targetIDnew > 0)
    {
        movement = -1;
        targetIDnew -= 1;
        f_addPage();
    }
}
function f_nextSlide():void
{
    if(targetIDnew < (numberOfPages.totalFrames - 1))
    {
        movement = 1;
        targetIDnew += 1;
        f_addPage();
    }
}

function f_addPage():void 
{ 
    // use the targetID variable to access the corresponding index in the pageArray and assign it to a temporary variable
    targetIDold = targetIDnew - movement;
    var _mcOld:MovieClip = MovieClip(pageArray[targetIDold]);
    var _mcNew:MovieClip = MovieClip(pageArray[targetIDnew]);
    //avoid flickering
    if (_mcNew.alpha == 1) {
        _mcNew.alpha = 0;
    }
    // add the temp variable to pageHolder
    pageHolder.addChild(_mcNew);
    // tween the temp variable to the specified properties, then call a function to remove the previous page
    // new page gets faded in, old page gets faded out
    TweenMax.to(_mcNew, 1.5, {alpha:1}); 
    TweenMax.to(_mcOld, 1.5, {alpha:0, onComplete:f_removePage}); 
} 

function f_removePage():void 
{ 
    // previous page will always be at index 0; remove it 
    // the new page just added will drop down to index 0 when the previous page is removed 
    pageHolder.removeChildAt(0); 
}

//Trying to advance / decrease the timeline in the movieclips of the single pages by pressing down / up
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, f_changeFrame);
function f_changeFrame(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == 40) // down arrow
    {
        f_nextFrame();
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 38) // up arrow
    {
        f_prevFrame();
    }
}
function f_nextFrame():void
{
        var w:uint = pageHolder.numChildren - 1 ;
        (pageHolder.getChildAt(w) as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(currentFrame + 1);
//      for (var i:uint = 0; i < pageHolder.numChildren; i++)
//      {
//       trace (+i+'.\t name:' + pageHolder.getChildAt(i).name + '\t type:' + typeof (pageHolder.getChildAt(i)));
//      }
        trace ("down!");
}

function f_prevFrame():void
{
        var w:uint = pageHolder.numChildren - 1 ;
        (pageHolder.getChildAt(w) as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(currentFrame - 1);
//      for (var i:uint = 0; i < pageHolder.numChildren; i++)
//      {
//       trace (+i+'.\t name:' + pageHolder.getChildAt(i).name + '\t type:' + typeof (pageHolder.getChildAt(i)));
//      }
        trace ("up!");
}
```

Edit: clarified code a bit

Edit2: TL;DR: Problem is the last bit of code with the three functions that fail to control the timeline of mc page1, which is a child of mc pages, which is pushed frame by frame into an array and loaded at runtime into the sprite pageHolder. How to control the timeline of the single page movieclips?

Comment: Can you be more specific about this statement - " What I do not get at all after several hours and lots of google searches is how to now control the single page movieclips."  It's not clear what you are stuck on. Try to narrow your question down to the exact issue.

Comment: The problem is: I have a movieclip called "pages", exported to Actionscript as "Pages". It consists of one frame for each page that gets added to the array and can be "browsed".

Comment: I'm still not following you. What is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't finish editing. Added this: I want to be able to put one movieclip on every frame of "pages" and make every child movieclip have several frames with a "stop();" in the first frame. Now I want to be able to move to other frames of the currently shown movieclip and back with the down and up arrow keys. The way my code is shown now, it doesn't move this movieclips timeline, but the one of the "pages"-movieclip. And if I try to add addEventListener to "pages" or to "page1", it doesn't work at all, can't trigger a trace command.

Comment: If you want to get answer fast and correctly,
minimize you issue.

Comment: The issue at hand is: How do I control the timeline of the movieclip with key presses that is a child of the movieclip that gets displayed via an array? I tried controlling it with movieclip.getChildAt.childmc, which gives an error, and I tried it with the addEventListener in the movieclip or the child movieclip itself, which plain doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: `pageHolder.w`? Why are you treating `pageHolder` as an array?

Comment: Am I treating pageHolder as an array? If so, I wasn't aware of it. Please point out any problems with my handling of variables, I did some scripting in AS 1.0 but have very little experience with AS 3.0, the code you see is half copy & paste and half trial & error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. This will work as a perfect powerpoint replacement :D

You will need to name the single slides (one movieclip on each frame of the mc `pages`) as `page0`, `page1` etc. and then can control their timeline with this code (just replace the functions listed in the question above):

```
function f_nextFrame():void
{
    var temp:uint = pageHolder.numChildren - 1;
    var frame:uint = ((pageHolder.getChildAt(temp) as MovieClip)["page" + targetIDnew].currentFrame);
    (pageHolder.getChildAt(temp) as MovieClip)["page" + targetIDnew].gotoAndStop(frame + 1);
}

function f_prevFrame():void
{
    var temp:uint = pageHolder.numChildren - 1;
    var frame:uint = ((pageHolder.getChildAt(temp) as MovieClip)["page" + targetIDnew].currentFrame);
    (pageHolder.getChildAt(temp) as MovieClip)["page" + targetIDnew].gotoAndStop(frame - 1);
}
```